# Schnirelmann Density: if $d(A) + d(B) \ge 1$, does it follow that $d(A+B)=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am still trying to get my head around the basic properties of Schnirelmann Density.

If I'm reading [PlanetMath.org](http://planetmath.org/schnirelmanndensity) correctly, it states that if $d(A) + d(B) \ge 1$, then $d(A+B)=1$

Here's the exact wording:

> and also if $\sigma{A} +\sigma{B} \ge 1$, then $\sigma(A+B)=1$.

This seems counter intuitive to me.  For example, let $A =$ the odd integers: $\left\{1, 3, 5, \dots\right\}$.  Let $B = A$.

Then, $d(A)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $d(B) = \frac{1}{2}$ so that $d(A)+d(B)=1$ but $d(A+B) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Here's my understanding of Schnirelmann Density.

- $A,B$ are infinite sequences of integers starting with $0$ with in sequential order such as $0, a_1, a_2, \cdots$ where $0 < a_1 < a_2 < \cdots$
- Schnirelmann density is defined as:
  $$d(A) = \inf\limits_{n}\frac{A(n)}{n}$$

where: $$A(n) = \sum\limits_{0<a_i\le{n}}{1}$$

- So, it is clear that:  $$0 \le \frac{A(n)}{n} \le 1$$

Is PlanetMath wrong?  Am I misunderstanding their statement about Schnirelmann Density?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, PlanetMath is right. It's just that they mean **sumset** when they add sets, i.e., $A+B=\mathbb{N}$ not $A+B=A$.

A **sumset** is the set of all possible sums from elements in $A$ and in $B$. Since $1\in A$, then you can add 1 to any odd integer and get $\mathbb{N}$.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumset

Additionally, Wikipedia explicitly says that they mean sumset in their article on the density. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnirelmann_density

Comment: Thanks very much!  That was my misunderstanding.  Thanks for the link on Sumset!